# Angular - Suppressing Broadly Defined Events for Narrowly Defined Contained Elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What if I want a broadly defined ng-click on a large panel, but I want any link tags to trigger the link behavior only and not the ng-click?  Example:

```
<div ng-click="doIt()">
    <div>Lots of other stuff...</div>

    <!-- I don't want this or any other links to trigger the ng-click behavior -->
    <a href='http://www.amazon.com' target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Not extremely familiar with angular, but could you just define your own javascript event listeners to call whatever ng-click was calling?

Comment: Well, I'd still prefer to keep ng-click in there because of its Angular coolness - just wondering if certain inner things can selectively override it, stop the event from propagating, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an `ng-click` to the links you don't want to be affected and use `$event.stopPropagation();`

In your controller.

```
$scope.dontDoIt = function($event){
    $event.stopPropagation();
};
```

Inside your view.

```
<div ng-click="doIt()">
    <div>Lots of other stuff...</div>

    <!-- I don't want this or any other links to trigger the ng-click behavior -->
    <a href='http://www.amazon.com' ng-click="dontDoIt($event)" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fE8fX/13/) example.